# Was this predatorial villain original to the movie?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-84

Late in *Wonder Woman 84* Diana fights hand-to-hand with an animalistic human who is a main character transformed into the ultimate predator. The villain has fur and claws while remaining humanoid.

Was this villain totally original to the movie, or obviously inspired by a character in DC comics or the 1980s *Wonder Woman* TV show?

Comment: Boo downvoters! Boooooo! Where's your Christmas spirit!?!

Comment: A short google search for „Wonder Woman 1984 villain“ shows that her name is Cheetah and that she is a main antagonist in the comics... it took longer to write the question than to google the answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That character’s name is [Cheetah](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheetah_(character)), and is considered Wonder Woman’s main nemesis in the comics.